# REST & SOAP questions

Tags: rest, soap, service, web

I have a few questions on REST & SOAP, was hoping someone can help out. They're pretty straight forward.

1. Which websites today use SOAP? I always find sites mainly use REST, but I need examples of sites using SOAP. So far I can only think of PayPal. Anyone know any others?
2. In what instance can you use SOAP in which you cannot use REST (without practicality atleast)? Like would a good example be when you want to communicate with your bank, because SOAP has security features (like WS-Security) that REST doesn't? Is there any other example?
3. Is there any improvements you believe SOAP can have to allow to be more competitive with REST?

Any answers or clues would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any improvements you believe SOAP can have to allow to be
>   more competitive with REST?

- Currently SOAP has way stronger positions compared to REST.
- 99% REST web services are not REST at all
- SOAP has good tooling and is way easier to implement
- Corporations have thousands of successfully deployed web ervices implemented in SOAP
- Web services like Twitter's API etc... are simpler to use though this doesn't mean
  that SOAP is not competitive.
- SOAP is not suitable for such uses though not Twitter nor other APIs like this are RESTful... you can call them resource oriented or HTTP APIs

Comment: Have any ideas about any of the other 2 questions?